# RESTSharp unable to find location header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an async Task in C# that returns

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage>
```

Code as follows

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(new Shared().ToAbsoluteUrl("~/html/fail.aspx"));
return response;
```

On codebehind of an ASPX page I have the following code

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.Headers.Any(t => t.Name == "Location"))
{
    string location = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Location").Value.ToString();
}
```

PROBLEM: I am unable to retrieve the location header value in codebehind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
client.FollowRedirects = false;
```

before this line:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```