# How To Get Location Header from RestSharp Response

Tags: oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm using the code below to get the "location" header from the RestSharp response headers.  But there is no "location" header in the Headers array so this method always returns Null.  How do I get RestSharp to return the location header?  I've seen another S/O post:

[RESTSharp unable to find location header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337231/restsharp-unable-to-find-location-header)

that says to set the RestClient option FollowRedirects to False.  But that doesn't appear to fix the problem.

```
static string GetLocation(string authUri, string clientId, string scope, Guid state, string callbackUri)
{
    var options = new RestClientOptions(authUri)
    {
        FollowRedirects = false
    };
    var client = new RestClient(options);

    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);
 
    request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
    request.AddParameter("response_type", "code");
    request.AddParameter("scope", scope);
    request.AddParameter("state", state);        
    request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", callbackUri);

    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return location = (string)response.Headers
                          .Where(x => x.Name == "Location")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
        throw new Exception(response.Content);
}
```

UPDATE: I've adjusted my code to include the required user credentials as shown below.  When I run it, the response header collection still doesn't have any "location" header.  If I try to get a token from this authorization server using Postman, I can see the location header in Postman's Console window.  I'm wondering why it's not appearing in RestSharp.  Does RestSharp not expose that header for some reason?

```
        static string GetAuthCode(string authUri, string clientId, string scope, Guid state, string callbackUri)
        {
            var options = new RestClientOptions(authUri)
            {
                FollowRedirects = false
            };
            var client = new RestClient(options);

            var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);

            client.Options.MaxTimeout = -1;

            request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
            request.AddParameter("response_type", "code");
            request.AddParameter("scope", scope);
            request.AddParameter("state", state);
            request.AddParameter("username", "XXXXXXXXX", true);
            request.AddParameter("password", "XXXXXXXXX", true);
            request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", callbackUri);

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                string location = (string)response.Headers.Where(x => x.Name == "Location")
                                                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                                                          .FirstOrDefault();

                return location; 
            }
            else
                throw new Exception(response.Content);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a code flow here, which should be run in the browser, not via a C# HTTP client.

The immediate response (after following redirects) is likely to be an HTML form where the user authenticates. Using the C# client prevents this from being possible.

After the user authenticates, a browser client will receives an authorization code (again, after following redirects). It should not be necessary to read response location headers in an OAuth flow.

If you are using a service account, the client credentials flow would be more standard, and also technically simpler:

```cs
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);

request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "my_service_account");
request.AddParameter("client_secret", "my_secret_value");
request.AddParameter("scope", scope);

RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I need to have the authentication automated by a service account so I believe I do need to read the response headers.  But now I see that my code isn't passing any credentials to the authentication server.  So that could be why it's not working.

Comment: Maybe try the client_credentials flow instead ...

Comment: I'm going to try that.  I'm just waiting for the API developer to give me the parameter names for the user ID and password.